# In Swift 3 after creating a button with a function, how do I change the properties of that button?

Tags: swift, xcode, function, button

New to xcode.  I'm using the following function to create a number of new buttons.  I want to animate individual buttons after they are created but am not sure how to interact with the new button.

function:

```
func createButton(buttonTitle: String, xaxis: Double, yaxis: Double) {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: xaxis, y: yaxis, width: 100.0, height: 30.0)
    button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(buttonTitle, comment: buttonTitle), for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.05 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.backgroundColor = .gray
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: You should return button from this func and use that return value to interact with it like `let button = createButton(...); button.setTitle("whatever")`.

Comment: Do I have to define the new variable as a UIButton first?  let button = UIButton.  button = createButton(...)?

Comment: Actually you can declare and assign at the same time. Just like I did above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Nick Allen you can change your function to return UIButton

```
func createButton(buttonTitle: String, xaxis: Double, yaxis: Double) -> UIButton {
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
return button 
}
```

//-- Then to create the button

```
let button1 = createButton(.....)
view.addSubview(button1).
```

Comment: This worked great.  I'm having trouble referring back to button1 outside of the function where I created it.  I've tried self.view.button1 and view.button1 without success.  Any suggestions on how to reference it?

Comment: @SwiftLanding do u know how many buttons you want to create or is it dynamic? if u know how many buttons, u can declare the button as variable inside of the viewcontroller, outside the function.

u can create like this:
var button1 : UIButton!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create an instance variable to hold a button, you can add a tag to your button and get a reference to it later.

To do so, add tag to the button:

```
button.tag = 300 // no other view should have the same tag to avoid issues
```

and then you can easily reference your button from anywhere in the view controller like this:

```
if let button = view.viewWithTag(300) as? UIButton {
    // change any properties of the button as you would normally do
    button.setTitle("Updated title", for: .normal)
}
```

I would suggest defining tag values in a constants at the top of the ViewController class to avoid using 'magic numbers' in your code.

Comment: Tag is reserved for IB, I don't think using tag like this is a good practice.

Comment: I agree to some extent, but if you are using view's tag property **only** to identify it (not to store some kind of data) then I don't see it as that bad.